# Error al mostrar resultados de un LinkedList en un JTextArea

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2

Mi programa aun no está terminado, si notan cosas tontas o validaciones raras es porque aún estoy probando, pero me gustaria que me ayudaran a poder imprimir los datos de mi lista enlazada ya que cuando veo los datos solo salen garabatos como estos
**java.util.LinkedList$ListItr@1cec7951**
cuando deberian imprimirse los datos que ingreso desde la interfaz grafica y nose que estoy haciendo mal, cabe recalcar que necesito recorrer el la lista con un iterador, por eso debo apegarme a imprimr el resultado luego de iterarlo, pero cuando imprimo solo me salen garabatos raros.

```java
public class IngresoPersonal {

    private String nombre;
    private String nacionalidad;
    private int edad;
    private String esquemaVacunacion;
    private String vacunacionInfluencia;

     LinkedList lista = new LinkedList();
    
     public IngresoPersonal(String nombre, String nacionalidad, int edad, String esquemaVacunacion, String vacunacionInfluencia){
     
        this.nombre =  nombre;
        this.nacionalidad = nacionalidad;
        this.edad = edad;
        this.esquemaVacunacion = esquemaVacunacion;
        this.vacunacionInfluencia = vacunacionInfluencia;
        
    }
    
    public IngresoPersonal(){
        
    }
    
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getNacionalidad() {
        return nacionalidad;
    }

    public void setNacionalidad(String nacionalidad) {
        this.nacionalidad = nacionalidad;
    }

    public int getEdad() {
        return edad;
    }

    public void setEdad(int edad) {
        this.edad = edad;
    }

    public String getEsquemaVacunacion() {
        return esquemaVacunacion;
    }

    public void setEsquemaVacunacion(String esquemaVacunacion) {
        this.esquemaVacunacion = esquemaVacunacion;
    }

    public String getVacunacionInfluencia() {
        return vacunacionInfluencia;
    }

    public void setVacunacionInfluencia(String vacunacionInfluencia) {
        this.vacunacionInfluencia = vacunacionInfluencia;
    }
       
    
    public void ingreso(){
        
       lista.add("Su nombre es :" + getNombre());
       lista.add("Su nacionalidad es :" + getNacionalidad());
       lista.add("Edad :" + getEdad());
       lista.add("Vacunacion Covic-19 :" + getEsquemaVacunacion());
       lista.add("Vacunacion Influencia :"  + getVacunacionInfluencia());
    }
    
    public LinkedList RetornarNombre(){
        
        return lista;
    }
    
    public Iterator<Object> mostrar(){
      Iterator <Object> iterator = lista.iterator();

        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            
            iterator.next();
            
        }
       return iterator;
        
    }
```

supongo que el problema esta en el metodo mostrar, pero nose como deberia imprimir correctamente con un iterador ya que en mi proyecto me lo exiguen.

aqui esta mi menu principal

```java
    private void jButton_guardarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                

        nombre = txt_nombre1.getText();
        edad = Integer.parseInt(txt_edad.getText());
        nacionalidad = combobox_nacionalidad.getSelectedItem().toString();

        if (jCheckBox1_esquemaVacunacion1.isSelected()) {

            esquemaVacunacion = "si";
            
        } else {
            
            esquemaVacunacion = "no";
        }

         if (jCheckBox1_vacunaInfluenza.isSelected()) {

            vacunacionInfluencia = "si";
            
        } else {
            
            vacunacionInfluencia = "no";
        }
               
        ingresopersonal = new IngresoPersonal(nombre, nacionalidad, edad, esquemaVacunacion, vacunacionInfluencia);
            ingresopersonal.ingreso();
    }                                               

//aqui es donde muestro osea imprimo en el textArea pero me imprime puros garabatos.
    private void btn_mostrarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        
        try {
           
            txtsiguiente.setText(" ");
            txtsiguiente.append(ingresopersonal.mostrar() + "\n");
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Necesitas tener el método mostrar? xq para que te fuera mas fácil te recomendaría hacer el iterator donde lo necesites y te olvides de crearte un método a parte.

Comment: Tu programa no tiene mucho sentido que digamos. La clase IngresoPersonal tiene los datos de un paciente, y además tiene una lista sin definir de qué tipo de objetos, en la que metes cadenas de caracteres del tipo: "Su nombre es: Juan". Y luego en la función mostrar iteras no sé para qué hasta el final y retornas un iterador, y ese iterador que es un objeto lo quieres mostrar en una caja de texto tal cual. Cuesta mucho darte una respuesta con sentido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes dos errores:

- Tu función mostrar devuelve un iterador ya "recorrido", lo que no sirve para nada
- Tu clase no ha sobreescrito el método `String toString()`, por lo que ese código no es capaz de mostrar los datos de las instancias de IngresoPersonal.

La solución sería:

- eliminar el método `mostrar` y directamente recorrer la lista con un for
- implementar el método toString(), seleccionando qué se quiere mostrar al convertirlo a texto.